# Python Omnidirectional calibration

Tags: python, camera-calibration

I am trying to calibrate an omnidirectional camera using python an opencv. Couldn't find any python code online to do so. I tried to make my own but it seems to be not working.

I modified the code for calibrating a fisheye lens camera.

```
import cv2
assert cv2.__version__[0] == '4', 'The fisheye module requires opencv version >= 3.0.0'
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
CHECKERBOARD = (5,8)
subpix_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1)
calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC+cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND+cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW
objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
_img_shape = None
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    if _img_shape == None:
        _img_shape = img.shape[:2]
    else:
        assert _img_shape == img.shape[:2], "All images must share the same size."
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(3,3),(-1,-1),subpix_criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)
N_OK = len(objpoints)
K = np.zeros((3, 3))
D = np.zeros((4, 1))
xi = np.zeros(1)
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]
rms, _, _, _, _, _ = \
    cv2.omnidir.calibrate(
        objpoints,
        imgpoints,
        gray.shape[::-1],
        K,
        xi,
        D,
        calibration_flags,
        (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1),
        rvecs,
        tvecs
    )
print("Found " + str(N_OK) + " valid images for calibration")
print("DIM=" + str(_img_shape[::-1]))
print("K=np.array(" + str(K.tolist()) + ")")
print("D=np.array(" + str(D.tolist()) + ")")
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error.
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (!omAll.empty() && omAll.depth() == patternPoints.depth()) || omAll.empty() in function 'calibrate'

Any ideas what needs to be changed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rvecs and tvecs need to have the same depth as your patternPoints and imagePOints, 
change

```
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_OK)]
```

to

```
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.floa32) for i in range(N_OK)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float32) for i in range(N_OK)]
```